# Which Bluemix service can be used to get references/text related to causes and solution given an error code/message?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I'd like to use Watson services in Bluemix to find the diagnosis and treatment for a given error code and message, for example: "P0087, Fuel Rail/System Pressure - Too Low, 1, Kia, 2009, Sportage".

As result of the service I'd like to get a reference like http://www.obd-codes.com/p0087, or get something similar to the "Causes" and "Solutions" text in that page.

Could you please advice which service to use and the best approach to get better results?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to suggest you two options and in both I'm doing lots of assumptions.

#### OPTION 1:

Use [Natural Language Classifier](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/nl-classifier.html) to identify the class/intent based on a short string of text, in this case the user query. Then you can either map the intent to a **solution** (1-1 map) or use something else to map the intent to the correct error.

#### OPTION 2:

Use Solr to index everything (error codes, solutions, causes, etc..) and then search it.

We have released a new service called [Retrieve and Rank](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/retrieve-rank.html). it will provision a Solr instance and allow you to create and train a "ranker" which is basically a machine learning plugin on top of solr that sort the responses according to some training-data.

Comment: Option 2 might be better, as option 1 would require at least 5 examples of the error message/question to train. It depends on who/what is looking for the solution.